# Is it possible to have all the Drawer Navigator screens having bottom tabs visible?

Tags: react-native, navigator, stack-navigator, react-navigation-drawer, react-native-tabnavigator

I am trying to implement Stack, Tab and Drawer navigators alltogether. I have a Profile screen inside the bottom tabs, which is a stack navigator component. When I open it from bottom tabs, the screen comes without any problem with bottom tabs visible. But when I open the same screen with drawer screen, bottom tabs are not shown.

The nested structure of the screens are like this:

```
<Drawer.Navigator >
   <Drawer.Screen name="Homepage" component={TabNavigator} />
   <Drawer.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
   .... // other screens with bottom tabs not visible
</Drawer.Navigator >
```

and

```
<Tab.Screen name="Stack" component={StackNavigator} />
<Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen}  />
```

Is it possible to achieve this?